# Why does groupby.transform function take a dataframe as the input for the last function call in the first group loop?

Tags: pandas, group-by, transform

```
# Generating a test dataframe
def get_data(stack=False):
    dic = {'APPL':[10,5,-4,8],'MSFT':[20,-9,12,4],'TSLA':[-8,15,-7,14]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(dic,index=pd.Series([2010,2011,2012,2013],name='date'))
    if stack:
        df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack()).reset_index()
        df.columns =['date','symbol','ret']
    return df

# Setting examples
dfs = get_data(stack=True).copy()


def f(x):
    global i
    print("-----------------------")
    print("Function call:", i,'\n')
    print("This is an input of function\n",x,'\n')
    i = i + 1

i = 1
dfs.groupby('date').transform(f)
```

I wanted to see what the inputs of a user-defined function are when I use a groupby transform method. As expected the first 2 inputs are columns (symbol, ret) of the first group (2010). But I don't see why the third input is the entire dataframe of the first group. So. the total number of function calls is 9, not 8 (= 4 groups times 2 columns).

I got the following result. The `function call 3` step confuses me.

```
---- stacked data ---- 
     date symbol  ret
0   2010   APPL   10
1   2010   MSFT   20
2   2010   TSLA   -8
3   2011   APPL    5
4   2011   MSFT   -9
5   2011   TSLA   15
6   2012   APPL   -4
7   2012   MSFT   12
8   2012   TSLA   -7
9   2013   APPL    8
10  2013   MSFT    4
11  2013   TSLA   14

======= Transform method ========
-----------------------
Function call: 1 

This is an input of function
 0    APPL
1    MSFT
2    TSLA
Name: symbol, dtype: object 

-----------------------
Function call: 2 

This is an input of function
 0    10
1    20
2    -8
Name: ret, dtype: int64 

-----------------------
Function call: 3 

This is an input of function
   symbol  ret
0   APPL   10
1   MSFT   20
2   TSLA   -8 

-----------------------
Function call: 4 

This is an input of function
 3    APPL
4    MSFT
5    TSLA
Name: symbol, dtype: object 

-----------------------
Function call: 5 

This is an input of function
 3     5
4    -9
5    15
Name: ret, dtype: int64 

-----------------------
Function call: 6 

This is an input of function
 6    APPL
7    MSFT
8    TSLA
Name: symbol, dtype: object 

-----------------------
Function call: 7 

This is an input of function
 6    -4
7    12
8    -7
Name: ret, dtype: int64 

-----------------------
Function call: 8 

This is an input of function
 9     APPL
10    MSFT
11    TSLA
Name: symbol, dtype: object 

-----------------------
Function call: 9 

This is an input of function
 9      8
10     4
11    14
Name: ret, dtype: int64
```